# UIControl Lifecycle

Tags: ios, uicontrol

Is there a documented Lifecycle for a UIControl somewhere?

Here's why I ask:

Suppose I have a UITextField.  I could easily wire up a button that changes the border color like so:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

Now suppose I have a custom control that's a subclass of UIControl.  That same code will not change the border color unless I also issue `setNeedsLayout`, like so:

```
[myControl setNeedsLayout];
```

Is there an event method somewhere that I need to implement to make this work without the `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: It ought to work without any additional effort from you. Are you sure you're setting it in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future generations, here's how I solved the problem on my own.

In my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, setter = setBorderColor:) UIColor *borderColor;
```

In my .m file:

```
- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)clr {
    borderColor = clr;
    myControl.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Having solved the problem, you might want to go back and edit the question (title especially) so that it's more relevant to what you found. I don't think you were really looking for a UIControl lifecycle (which is about the same as for any view), and the solution here only relates to how to update the border color without needing the `-setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: The reason I asked about the control lifecycle is that I suspect I could do this work during a pre-existing action.  Something similar to viewWillAppear for a UIViewController.  Instead, I had to hack together a solution at the time the property I need is changed.  I still think doing the application of the new border would be better suited to a lifecycle method, don't you?